# How to use parameters in Entity Framework in a "in" clause?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, parameters

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 and I want to use the following query:

To do that I do the following:

```
strSQLQuery = "select * from MyTable where IDData IN (@IDs)";
lstParameters.Clear();
myParameter = new SqlParameter("@IDs", strIDs);
lstParameters.Add(myParameter);

myContext.MyTable.SqlQuery(strSQLQuery, lstParameters.ToArray<object>()).ToList<MyTable>();
```

But I get an exception that say that it is not possible to convert `nvarchar` to `bigint`.

That is because the parameter is the type string, and the IDs in the table are `bigint`.

I try to create a list of long and add some IDs, but I get other error.

How can I use a list o IDs as parameter in a query?

I would like to use parameters, if that is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First off, to fix your data type error, you'd have to convert `strIDs` to integers before doing anything else. This should work

```
var ids = strIDs.Select(s => long.Parse(s));
```

Now, since you're using entity framework already, why not use Linq instead of creating a SQL query?

```
var results =
    from r in myContext.MyTable
    where ids.Contains(r.IDData)
    select r;
```

Or in fluent syntax

```
var results = myContext.MyTable.Where(r => strIDs.Contains(r.IDData));
```

But if you really want to use SQL, the `IN` operator does not support parameters like that. You'd have to write it like this:

```
strSQLQuery = "select * from MyTable where IDData IN(@ID1, @ID2, @ID3, ...)";
```

So to do this without too much effort, you can generate your query from `ids` like this:

```
strSQLQuery = "select * from MyTable where IDData IN(" + String.Join(", ", ids.Select((s, i) => "@ID" + i)) + ")";
foreach(var parameter in ids.Select((s, i) => new SqlParameter("@ID" + i, s)))
{
    lstParametros.Add(parameter);
}
```

Comment: If your query doesnt use any other parameters, then you can also replace the last step with this...

strSQLQuery = "select * from MyTable where IDData IN (" + String.Join(", ", ids.Select((s, index) => "@p" + i)) + ")";
                var results = context.MyTable.SqlQuery(query, ids.Cast<object>().ToArray());

Comment: there is limitation in using x.Contains to emulate IN.. Oracle can handle around 1000 INs.. so if you get 1001 values you get stack overflow (pun intended!) :)

Comment: @BoppityBop Good to know. Do you know if it's dependent on the number of total parameters or specifically the number of items passed in the `IN` clause? If it's the latter, you may be able to get around this by splitting into multiple `IN`'s like `IDData IN(…) OR IDData IN(…) OR IDData IN(…)` -- although granted, if you get to that point, there's probably something else you're doing wrong and you may want to rethink your strategy.

Comment: I need to experiment a bit with it.. This might be specific to the 3rd party Oracle Data Provider and their EF driver we use (Oracle dotConnect). But I had to change bunch of code because I caught stack overflow so it is fact. I don't know if `OR` will work