# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ') in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't find the error in the code but it showing me.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')

My code is here:

```
private void ShowChart()
{
    string UserID = "";

    for (int Counter = 0; Counter < UID.Count - 1; Counter++)
    {
        UserID += UID[Counter].ToString() + ",";
    }

    UserID = UserID.Substring(0, UserID.Length);

    string[] ListFamily = { };
    int[] ListTime = { };

    var Query = Database.Database.SqlQuery<Vw_ShowChartInfo>("Select * From Vw_ShowChartInfo Where UserID In (" + UserID + ")").ToList();

    for (int I = 0; I < Query.Count; I++)
    {
        Family.Add(Query[I].FullName.ToString());
        Time.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Query[I].TotalTime));
        ListFamily = Family.ToArray();
        ListTime = Time.ToArray();
    }

    this.Chart.Series.Clear();
    this.Chart.Palette = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.Pastel;
    this.Chart.Titles.Add("نمودار کارکرد پرسنل");

    for (int II = 0; II < ListFamily.Length; II++)
    {
        Series series = this.Chart.Series.Add(ListFamily[II] + "-" + Query[II].TotalTime);
        series.Points.Add(ListTime[II]);
    }
}
```

[image: Error in C#]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection), or possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085812/how-to-use-parameters-in-entity-framework-in-a-in-clause

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `UserID` (please don't guess)?

Comment: Your code is not removing the last comma added in the initial loop. You should write _UserID = UserID.Substring(0, UserID.Length-1);_ Also the loop is missing to add the last element from the UID collection, not sure if this is an error or if you really don't want the last item

Comment: Also you should really read about Sql Injection. We don't know what is UID and from which source you initialize it but is a really good practice to use parameters when writing this kind of database code. The parameterization of the IN clause is problematic but still you should use parameters. [Read here about IN clause using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: I'd also suggest changing your second for loop to `Family.AddRange(Query.Select(z => z.FullName.ToString())); Time.Add(Query.Select(z => Convert.ToInt32(z.TotalTime))); ListFamily = Family.ToArray(); ListTime = Time.ToArray();` since it is much more concise and likely faster.

Comment: For other visitors, please **do not** follow the accepted answer here. It is likely open to SQL Injection. Please read the links that @Steve and I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be this line:

```
UserID = UserID.Substring(0, UserID.Length);
```

The string you are generating contains a comma at the end. It looks like you are attempting to trim the comma with that line but you are simply selecting the same string again. Use this instead:

```
UserID = UserID.Substring(0, UserID.Length - 1);
```

Also, the assumption is your user ids are numeric. Otherwise, you would need to surround them with single quotes.

That being said, it's a terrible idea to concatenate strings this way as it leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Consider a different approach.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to tell beginners to put SQL injection vulnerabilities in their code.

Comment: @DourHighArch: I think no one would disagree, but a question was asked and an answer was given. I think the votes are meant to rate the quality of the answer with regards to the question, not how well we can refactor code. Either way, I still mentioned it at the bottom of my answer. Happy New Year!