# Linq RemoveAll with ContainsList instead of AddArrayParameters

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I convert this SQL command query to Entity Framework Linq? Trying to remove a contains list.

Trying to utilize resource

```
    public async Task<int> PurgeInventory(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        var command =  new SqlCommand("Update [dbo].[Inventory] set status = 0 where InventoryId in ({ids})");
        command.AddArrayParameters("ids", ids);
        return await UnitOfWork.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(command);
    }
```

My attempt - looking for fix syntax:

```
   IEnumerable<int> ids = new IEnumerable<int>();

   UnitOfWork.DBSet<Inventory>().Remove(x => Where(x => InventoryId.Contains(ids));
```

Resource: [How to use parameters in Entity Framework in a "in" clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085812/how-to-use-parameters-in-entity-framework-in-a-in-clause)

Comment: _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large bulk delete operations it's generally better to do that as a raw SQL statement, however if you have a manageable number of rows to delete:

(fast)

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = getIdsToDelete();
var idRecords = ids.Select(x => new Inventory { InventoryId = x }).ToList();

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   foreach(var idRecord in idRecords)
   {
      context.Inventory.Attach(idRecord);
      context.Inventory.Remove(idRecord);
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This requires a new Context instance which will not have any Inventory records possibly loaded, and requires that the Inventory ID's selected to remove contain no duplicates. We convert the IDs into dummy Inventory entities then attach them to the DbContext and tell EF to remove them.

(thorough)

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = getIdsToDelete();

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var idRecords = context.Inventory.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.InventoryId)).ToList();

   foreach(var idRecord in idRecords)
      context.Inventory.Remove(idRecord);

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This one retrieves the entities from the context then removes them. In cases where you want to update related records or otherwise manage relationships, this along with remembering to `.Include()` those relationships would be the way.