# EF Core FromSql with IN Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-2.2

How to pass a dynamic list of int to FromSql method?
i tried the following code but it not works.

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

```
var result = dataContext.Customers.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id IN ({string.Join(",", listOfInt)})")
```

Comment: What do you mean with _it not works_? Error message?

Comment: @Steve Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

Comment: Try using _FromSqlInterpolated_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: If listOfInt is accessible in SQL, it should be calculated in `Query`. Otherwise, even if you work with the `entityframework`, you will have to submit the list, and if the list is too large, the Query will be `delayed`.

Comment: @Steve it's not available in ef core 2.2

Comment: It seems like the FromSql makes some changes to your string. I would try to prepare a variable with the sql text and pass that variable to see if this change happens also in this way

Comment: @steve Exactly. i use a variable for sql text and pass it to FromSql and it works. thanks.

Comment: One of the advantages of the `Entity-Framework` is that you can use LINQ to solved these kinds of problems with strong types and knowing property names (although you are unlikely to misspell "Id" some column names might not be so obvious). With LINQ you could do something like: `dataContext.Customers.Where(w => listOfInt.Any(l => l.Contains(w.Id)));`

Comment: @Barns My real query is so much heavier than this. i just simplified it to make it easier to read and answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use parameters in Entity Framework in a "in" clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085812/how-to-use-parameters-in-entity-framework-in-a-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var result = dataContext.Customers.FromSql(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id IN ({0})", string.Join(",", listOfInt)));
```

It does complain about injection vulnerability however but easy to sanitise a list of int at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
var Ids = string.Join(',', listOfInt.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());

var result = dataContext.Customers.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id IN ({Ids})")
```

Comment: What kind of is the `Id` value type?

Comment: How about this query? 
`var result = dataContext.Customers.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id IN (" + string.Join(",", listOfInt) + ")");`